# 01403. 00000 - "no data found" : PL/SQL block problem: No data found error

Tags: sql, plsql

When I am running the following piece of code in my procedure I am getting no data found error.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO v_Spouse_Applicant_Count
      FROM enrollment e,
        applicant a
      WHERE e.id                    = eachEnrl.id
      AND e.id                      = a.enrollment_id
      AND a.relationship_id         =2;
      dbms_output.put_line('Spouse applicant count' || v_Spouse_Applicant_Count);
```

The output for following line is showing as 1, still getting the error

Comment: What is `eachEnrl`? Is your posted query not your full query?

Comment: It is a small part of my whole procedure where error report is pointing

Comment: This piece of code can't return NO_DATA_FOUND, which means that you *wrongly* identified a culprit.

Comment: Aggregate function without `group by` always returns a row .